# pagination on distinct values in Hazelcast aggregator

Tags: mapreduce, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using hazelcast 3.6.1. I have implemented custom mapreduce for aggregation as i need solr facet kind of results, distinct value and its count.

I need the results from aggregate mapreduce in sorted by count desc with pagination support.

is there any way to achieve with in built options of hazelcast ?

i have added a custom collator and implemented it ? but it loads all data into memory and sort and apply pagination. is there any better way to handle this ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible. To find and count distinct values across partitions, you need to aggregate in a central place and then sort. I don't see how that can be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

Currently that's not possible. Stay tuned for forthcoming Map-Reduce improvements.

Comment: Thanks. Is adding custom collator to sort and apply pagination is correct ?